# Javascript DOM: Pinpointing "input" elements by their type?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a need to find and manipulate `<input type="checkbox">` from a table. At the moment I have a very spartan function:

```
function testAjaxCheckBoxes() {
    var table = document.getElementById("ajax_output");
    var nodeList = table.getElementsByTagName("input");
}
```

That is all I know how to do at the moment. I have a `nodeList` object of all tags of `<input>`, but I don't know how to check each one's type or attributes.

I suppose the more general question is how do you view and manipulate attributes of any kind through DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getAttribute(attr);`

so, if you want to check each item in the nodeList to see if it's a fileupload...

```
  var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(item in nodeList) {
    if(nodeList[item].getAttribute("type") == "file") {
     alert("i'm a file");   
    }
    else {
     alert(nodeList[item].getAttribute("type"));
    }
};
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. I'm using Eclipse, and being new depend on auto complete/templates. If I call upon nodeList[0]. then try autocomplete, no suggestions. Is my dev environment sparse or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Danedo: Auto-completion does not necessarily work in dynamic typed environments. But luckily, documentation still exists ;)

Comment: Your dev environment is sparse, yeah. There's no way for "IntelliSense" or autocomplete to know what's gonna be in the array. You gotta code it the hard way, unfortunately. :)

Comment: Important note (via MSDN): *The sAttrName parameter requires the name of the desired content attribute and not the Document Object Model (DOM) attribute. For example, in IE8 mode, this method no longer requires sAttrName to be "className" when setting, getting, or removing a CLASS attribute. **Earlier versions of Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer 8 in compatibility mode still require sAttrName to specify the corresponding DOM property name.*** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Matt thanks for the note. We can pretty much count on you for those types of things. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have the luxury of targeting Firefox >=3.5 and IE >=8, you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]")
```

to get an array of DOM elements as desired. [See more at the MDC documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: In his case the selector would be `#ajax_output input[type=file]` though.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have an element, you can use the [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute), [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute), and [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute) methods to read, write, and remove attributes.

Comment: I am guessing @Danedo wants to use a `for (var i; i < nodeList.length; i++)` loop. Inside that just put conditionals, eg `if (nodeList[[i]].getAttribute('type') == 'some value') { doSomething }`

Answer (score 0):

If you where to use a library (you should) like JQuery/Mootools etc
It would look like that

`var inputs=$('#ajax_output input[type=checkbox]');`

OR

```
var inputs=$('ajax_output').getElements('input[type=checkbox]');`
```